# Como usar sum com condição relativa a outro campo

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela de avaliações no formato

```
TABLE AVALIACAO
(id_avaliacao, id_pessoa, concluida, segunda_avaliacao)
```

e outra tabela que registra as notas

```
TABLE NOTA
(id_nota, id_avaliacao, id_questao, nota)
```

Bem abstratamente, o que acontece é que uma pessoa pode ter uma segunda avaliação caso peça isso. Nesse caso, o valor do campo segunda_avaliacao seria `char 'S'`.

Minha pergunta: como eu faço um sql que pegue o somatório de NOTA.nota, agrupando por pessoa (pelo `id_pessoa`) e que, caso seja uma segunda avaliação, pegue o somatório somente da segunda avaliação, em vez das duas.

Por exemplo.

```
AVALIAÇÂO

id_avaliacao id_pessoa concluida segunda_avaliacao
1            1         'S'       'N'
2            1         'S'       'S'
```

NOTA
TABLE NOTA

```
id_nota id_avaliacao id_questao nota
1       1            1          1
2       1            2          1
3       1            3          1
4       2            1          2
5       2            2          2
6       2            3          2
```

Como a pessoa 1 teve uma segunda avaliação, o somatório das notas dela deve ser 6 (e não 9).

Comment: Passando por aqui novamente, fiquei curioso pra saber se minha query resolveu seu problema, então resolvi testá-la. De fato resolve como eu pensei da primeira vez. Eis o teste: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/276805/1/0. Seu problema foi resolvido? Deixe o pessoal que tentou ajudá-lo saber.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    A.id_pessoa, SUM (N.nota)
FROM
    NOTA N 
    JOIN AVALIAÇÂO A on A.id_avaliacao = N.id_avaliacao
WHERE
    (
        A.segunda_avaliacao = 'N'
        AND NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT
                    id_avaliacao 
                FROM
                    AVALIAÇÂO
                WHERE
                    id_pessoa = A.id_pessoa 
                    and segunda_avaliacao = 'S'
            )
    )
    OR A.segunda_avaliacao = 'S'
GROUP BY
    A.id_pessoa
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries e CASE devem resolver:

```
select a.id_avaliacao, a.id_pessoa, a.concluida, a.segunda_avaliacao, 
    (case when a.segunda_avaliacao = 'S' then
        (select sum(nota) from nota where id_avaliacao = a.id_avaliacao and a.segunda_avaliacao = 'S')
     else (select sum(nota) from nota where id_avaliacao = a.id_avaliacao and a.segunda_avaliacao = 'N')
    end) as nota
from avaliacao a
where ...
```